# WebStorm and jsdoc3, defining allowed parameters doesn't work?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Based on [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/creating-jsdoc-comments.html), the JSDoc implementation in WebStorm seems to be very limited. Is there anyway to extend it? I can't find any plugins.

Specifically, I would like "allowed parameters" to work ([as implemented 2014-04-11](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/629#issuecomment-58766768))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they do work - if the argument doesn't match the value specified in `@param` annotation, WebStorm shows type mismatch warning:

[image]

But parameter hint shows expected parameter type, not value

Comment: "Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type string", I'm not sure I'd call that "working", but I see your point :)